# Howto call values from the store to enter as parameter to another service in effects ngrx in angular

Tags: angular, parameters, ngrx, store, effects

I would like to call an effects ngrx, but this effect have to call first a value from the store (an object with name and ids as number), then concatenate the ids to a string , then passing this string to another service.

I have this but it´s not working, can anyone help. Thanks

```
loadAllActifs$ = createEffect(() => {
return this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(fromActifActions.DoAction.loadAllActifs),
  withLatestFrom(
    this.store.select<IEntityModel[] | null>(selectAllUserFilter)
      .pipe(
        tap((lstDataEntitiesUser) => {
            if(lstDataEntitiesUser!=undefined && lstDataEntitiesUser?.length>0)
            {
              const userFiter_Id: number[] = [];
              lstDataEntitiesUser?.forEach(((_userFiter) =>
              {
                userFiter_Id.push(_userFiter.Id);
              }))
              return userFiter_Id.toString();
            }
            return '';
          }),
      )),
  concatMap(
     (entitiesUserList_Id) => this.actifsService.getActifs(entitiesUserList_Id)
    .pipe(
      catchError( error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.actifsError = {
          ...error,
          from:"Actif"
        };
        return of(<IActifModel[]>[]);
      })
    )
  ),
  map((actifsValues: IActifModel[]) =>
    {
      if(_.isEmpty(this.actifsError))
        return fromActifActions.DoAction.allActifsLoaded({ actifsValues })
      else
        return fromActifActions.DoAction.actifsError({ errorNotification:this.actifsError})
    }
    )
)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define "but it´s not working" to get a more detailed response, but here a few points:

- `tap` doesn't return anything, if you want to return a value, use the `map` operator.
- use `concatLatestFrom` instead of `withLatestFrom` https://ngrx.io/guide/eslint-plugin/rules/prefer-concat-latest-from

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help,

I find by myself the solution.
This is working

```
private lstEntitiesUserIds$ = this.store.select<string>(fromAccueilSelector.DoSelector.selectAllUserFilterStcIds)

  loadAllActifs$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType(fromActifActions.DoAction.loadAllActifs),
        withLatestFrom(this.lstEntitiesUserIds$),
        concatMap(
                  ([,entitiesUserList_stc_Id]) => this.actifsService.getActifs(entitiesUserList_stc_Id)
                  .pipe(
                    catchError( error => {
                      console.log(error);
                      this.actifsError = {
                        ...error,
                        from:"Actif"
                      };
                      return of(<IActifModel[]>[]);
                    })
                  )
                ),
                map((actifsValues: IActifModel[]) =>
                  {
                    if(_.isEmpty(this.actifsError))
                      return fromActifActions.DoAction.allActifsLoaded({ actifsValues })
                    else
                      return fromActifActions.DoAction.actifsError({ errorNotification:this.actifsError})
                  }
                  )
  )});
```